# Eclipse not building aidl file

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I'm having trouble getting eclipse to build an aidl file for android.  It doesn't seem to recognize it and does not call "aidl" when building project.

Comment: Maybe you should elaborate your question (modify your question). The more information you give the more likely we could help. What version of eclipse you have? What plugins are installed?

Answer (score 5):

You might have resolved the problem, but for others' reference, i corresponding .java files would not have been generated.So once clean the project and if that doesn't work delete the gen folder and then try building the project. It worked for me.

Comment: +1, deleting the gen folder and rebuilding the project fixed this issue.

Comment: me2, only cost 3+ hours.

Answer (score 1):

did you look inside the gen folder, where generated classes are stored?
that was my problem, I just looked at the wrong folder.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, be sure that your `.aidl` files are placed in the same package as of your `.java` files inside `src` folder.

You can check this by clicking mouse right click on `.aidl` file and check the path of this file. If the path does not contains your package name mentioned inside `src` folder, then copy the `.aidl` file and place it inside the package mentioned inside the `src` folder.

After this, clean the project and build it and see in `gen` folder, `.java` files will be generated for the respective `.aidl` files.

Answer (score 0):

You might encounter this issue if you don't have the aidl binary on your system, which is to say if you haven't installed the **Android SDK Build-tools** package from the Android SDK Manager.